# How to convert a string type to an array of chars

Tags: d, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to translate some C code to D, and I've come across this:

```
char[] welcome = "\t\tWelcome to the strange land of protected mode!\r\n";
```

It gives this warning:

```
main.d:5:18: error: cannot implicitly convert expression ("\x09\x09Welcome to the strange land of protected mode!\x0d\x0a") of type string to char[]
    5 | char[] welcome = "\t\tWelcome to the strange land of protected mode!\r\n";
      |                  ^
```

How do I do this without typing each character out individually in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[12.16.1 - Strings](https://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#strings)

> 1. A `string` is an array of characters. String literals are just an easy way to write character arrays. String literals are immutable
>      (read only).
>
>    ```d
>    char[] str1 = "abc";                // error, "abc" is not mutable
>    char[] str2 = "abc".dup;            // ok, make mutable copy
>    immutable(char)[] str3 = "abc";     // ok
>    immutable(char)[] str4 = str1;      // error, str4 is not mutable
>    immutable(char)[] str5 = str1.idup; // ok, make immutable copy
>    ```
> 2. The name string is aliased to `immutable(char)[]`, so the above declarations could be equivalently written as:
>
>    ```d
>    char[] str1 = "abc";     // error, "abc" is not mutable
>    char[] str2 = "abc".dup; // ok, make mutable copy
>    string str3 = "abc";     // ok
>    string str4 = str1;      // error, str4 is not mutable
>    string str5 = str1.idup; // ok, make immutable copy
>    ```

So:

```d
char[] welcome = "\t\tWelcome to the strange land of protected mode!\r\n".dup;
```

Comment: @JL2210 Um. Arrays are part of the language.

Comment: No, `.dup` is implemented in Druntime. Memory allocated by `.dup` is managed, i.e. owned by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, strings already are an array of chars. In fact, here is the definition of `string`:

```
alias string = immutable(char)[];
```

(from [object.d](https://github.com/dlang/druntime/blob/475fe24f658c2bf1f25ed39ad1530ec086595e87/src/object.d#L35))

A `string` thus differs from a `char[]` only in that the contents of the array is `immutable`.

- Depending on your goal, you may not need a `char[]` after all, and `string` will work as well.
- If you need the array to be writable (i.e. you expect `welcome[2] = 'x';` to work), then using `.dup` will create a copy at runtime.
- Sometimes C function declarations are not properly annotated with `const`, and will not accept pointers to immutable characters. In this case, using a `cast` is acceptable.
- I don't think there is a language feature to place a string literal directly in a writable data segment, in the same way that `static char[] s = ['a', 'b', 'c'];` does, but it's likely doable as a template or CTFE function.